# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.awt.AWTPermission" "accessClipboard")

Tags: java, security, applet

When I load my applet I get the Exception

`java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.awt.AWTPermission" "accessClipboard")`.

Have googled for couple of hours and have seen the answers like,

1. Adding the permissions in java policy - This is strictly internal process. But need to work in all machines.
2. Adding applet tag instead of object - Didn't work for me.
3. Keytool to be used to sign the applets - Have added the custom certificate to sign the applets. Still getting the exception.

Please help out guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Javascript within Java to get to the privileged methods:

http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/2/19/Accessing-privileged-methods-in-a-Java-Applet-via-JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have tried this now. Still I see the same exception. :(

Comment: @yakovsh.. This link just saved my day with some small tweek on return statement. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

@yakovsh : The blog is really helpful. Just a small change worked for me...

```
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new java.security.PrivilegedAction(){
            public Object run() {
                // execute the privileged command
                executeCommand(cmd);
                // we must return an object, so we'll return an empty string
                return new Object();
            }
        }
    );
```

The only change is with the return statement from `return ""` to `return new Object()`